# How to make project supported to the latest API, when it was created in lower API?

Tags: android

I receive an error from my already successfully runned project, when I import it in another eclipse on a different system.

The error i get is:
Can't resolve the target sdk"17"
 What,ll I do to support that,s projects on sdkmanager that support API level-18?

Comment: You are actually missing SDKs, nothing to do with code.

Comment: IDE that it,s now impoted is the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the android SDK and download the SDK version 17. You may have to restart Eclipse or do a project -> clean to make it work correctly.

Or else, just right click the project, go to properties, and under the 'Android' option, you can view a list of the SDKs you currently have installed.

Comment: In check it  API-19 is installed, so what I,ll do to install API-17?

Comment: When you right click on the project, try selecting API level 19 and then doing a project->clean in Eclipse.